# Jquery Getting a relative path for an image swap (not the rollover image)

Tags: jquery, image, replace, path

I am trying to replace an image when a link in another part of the page is rolled over. I have a hard coded version working, but I would like to get this so that when I upload to a server I do not need to go in and change the path part.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.laundryLinks li a').hover(function() {
 $('.homeLaundryPict').attr('src', 'http://192.168.1.2:8888/karenMaezenMiller/wp-content/themes/karenMillerTheme/i/laundryHome_quote.jpg'); },
 function() {
 $('.homeLaundryPict').attr('src', 'http://192.168.1.2:8888/karenMaezenMiller/wp-content/themes/karenMillerTheme/i/laundryHome_noQuote.jpg'); });
});
```

PS. I also played with trying to just replace a bit of source but had no luck

```
$(this).src.replace("_quote","_noQuote");
```

Comment: How does your document look like?

Comment: Can't you just use relative links?  (Relative to the page or the root of the site/application that is.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the following to get this to work:

```
$(this)[0].src = $(this)[0].src.replace(/_quote/, '_noQuote');
```

Hope it helps!

**EDIT**

```
$(function() {
    $('.laundryLinks li a').hover(function() {
        with ( $('.homeLaundryPict')[0] )
            src = src.replace(/_quote/, '_noQuote');
    }, function() {
        with ( $('.homeLaundryPict')[0] )
            src = src.replace(/_noQuote/, '_quote');
    });
});
```

Here you go ...

Comment: Thank you aefxx, how do I intergrate .homeLaundryPict into this though? The following did not work. Cheers.

$(document).ready(function() {
$('.laundryLinks li a').hover(function() {
 $('.homeLaundryPict').src = $(this)[0].src.replace(/_noQuote/, '_quote'));
; },
 function() {
 $('.homeLaundryPict').src = $(this)[0].src.replace(/_quote/, '_noQuote');
); });
});

Comment: sorry for the mess of code, it does not see, to let me put it in a code tag

Answer (score 0):

the replace you want to do should be

```
$img = $('#img_selector');
$img.attr('src', $img.attr('src').replace("_quote","_noQuote") );
```

***[update]***

You code (*in the comment*) has some syntax errors.. (*following is the corrected version..*)

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('.laundryLinks li a').hover(
    function() { 
      $img = $('.homeLaundryPict'); 
      $img.attr('src', $img.attr('src').replace("_noQuote","_quote") );
    }
    , 
    function() { 
      $img = $('.homeLaundryPict'); 
      $img.attr('src', $img.attr('src').replace("_quote","_noQuote") );
  } );
});​
```

Comment: I tried this with no luck, syntax errors?

$(document).ready(function() {
$('.laundryLinks li a').hover(function() {
 $img = $('.homeLaundryPict');
 $img.attr('src', $img.attr('src').replace("_noQuote","_quote") );,
 function() {
 $img = $('.homeLaundryPict');
 $img.attr('src', $img.attr('src').replace("_quote","_noQuote") ););
});

Comment: replace(regexp, String) is the correct signature not replace(String, String). See my answer, please.

Comment: @aefxx, according to http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp it can be either a regex or a string..

Comment: @Eric C, you close the inner functions with ) instead of } have a look at your code.. I will add it in my answer as update..

Comment: thank you very much, this is the result of a designer trying to code! Alas something still seems to be missing...

Comment: the images (img tags) have the `homeLaundryPict` class right ? (you have a live url where we can see it ?)

Comment: this shows a maintenance mode page... i meant if you have some url where we can see the page with the problem..

Comment: that is odd, I turned it off, should be visible now. Cheers.

Comment: maintenance mode is back on since aefxx provided a great solution below. The site will launch later this week. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (assuming only the first element will swap):

```
var pic = $('.homeLaundryPict')[0];
var orig = pic.src;
$('.laundryLinks li a').hover(function() {
    pic.src = pic.src.replace(/_quote/,"_noQuote");
}, function() {
    pic.src = orig;
});
```

Comment: This looks like it should work, however it does not. Thanks though!